# how to monitor etcd cluster status like what zookeeper's 4 letter word command 'srvr' does

Tags: etcd

I want to monitor the throughout like req/sec and latency of each endpoint in the etcd cluster, I know that zookeeper has 4 letter word command 'srvr' can do this., has any tools in etcd?
Thanks for any kind of help!